# Prove that $\binom{n+2} {k} = \binom{n} k + 2\binom n {k-1} + \binom n {k-2}$

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to solve the following combinatorics question:

> Prove that
>
> $$\binom{n+2} {k} = \binom{n} k + 2\binom n {k-1} + \binom n {k-2}$$

Comment: Can you please state the problem? For instance, what $n$ and $k$ are, and so on.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Thank for the quick reactions. I am working whole day to prove it using formula manipulation. I can't get further then (n+2,k) = ((n+2)(n+1)n!, k!(n+2-k!)), but maybe this is even wrong.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

> $$\binom{n+2}{k}=\binom{n+1}{k}+\binom{n+1}{k-1}\tag{1}$$Can you take it from here? You can use relation $(1)$ more than once, for instance how can you express: $$\binom{n+1}{k}=\dots\\\binom{n+1}{k-1}=\dots$$

Answer (score 1):

We have $n+2$ balls, $2$ are red and $n$ blue (all of different sizes).

On how many way can we choose $k$ balls?

Answer:

We can chose $0$ red and $k$ blue balls, that is ${2\choose 0}{n\choose k}$.

We can chose $1$ red and $k-1$ blue balls, that is ${2\choose 1}{n\choose k-1}$ combinations.

We can chose $2$ red and $k-2$ blue balls, that is ${2\choose 2}{n\choose k-2}$ combinations.

Comment: thank you, though this a combinatoric proof and not formulaic.

Comment: @MahsunDogan  Yes, are you not satisfied?

Comment: it is good enough> thank you for the effort!